kann man "auf etwas setzen" als "focus on" benutzen?
Während des Lesens bin ich auf einen Satz gestoßen. (Ich lerne deutsch, ich bin noch nicht perfekt. Falls ich einige Fehler mache, können Sie mich korrigieren). Der Satz lautet :

Er hat ein Start-up gegründet, das auf Nachhaltigkeit setzt.

auf etwas setzen bedeutet nicht "focus on sth" (wie ich schon in Langenscheit gesehen habe), aber wenn ich diesen Satz übersetze, sehe ich, dass es in dieser Bedeutung benutzt wir. Ist das richtig? kann man auf deutsch auf etw. setzen im Sinne von "tofocus on sth." benutzen ?

Nein, die beiden Ausdrücke haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.
"Auf etwas setzen" stammt aus dem Glücksspiel-Kontext. In vielen Glücksspielen wettet man Geld auf bestimmte Ereignisse. Das kann zum Beispiel sein, auf welche Zahl die Kugel beim Roulette fällt, oder welches Pferd ein Rennen gewinnt. In solchen Fällen sagt man, man setzt Geld auf ein bestimmtes Ereignis. Beispielsweise setzt man Geld darauf, dass beim Roulette die Zahl 5 fällt, oder darauf, dass das Pferd "Schnell wie der Wind" das nächste Rennen gewinnt. Hat man richtig gesetzt und das Ereignis tritt tatsächlich ein, bekommt man in der Regel einen Gewinn.
Im übertragenen Sinn wird der Ausdruck "auf etwas setzen" ebenfalls verwendet. Es bedeutet generell, dass man darauf spekuliert, dass ein bestimmtes Ereignis eintritt. Wenn das Ereignis tatsächlich eintritt, profitiert man davon.
Beispiele:

Das Team setzt darauf, das gegnerische Team gar nicht erst an den Ball kommen zu lassen.
Viele Kunden setzen auf das Fachwissen unserer Spezialisten.
Das Gütesiegel setzt auf das Grundprinzip der ökologischen Forstwirtschaft.

Im genannten Beispiel

Er hat ein Start-up gegründet, das auf Nachhaltigkeit setzt.

ist der Zusammenhang etwas indirekt. Das Start-up setzt offenbar darauf, dass Nachhaltigkeit (in seinem Geschäftsbereich) eine größere Bedeutung bekommt und die Firma damit gute Geschäfte machen kann. Sollte sich herausstellen, dass anstelle von Nachhaltigkeit zum Beispiel besonders niedrige Preise eine größere Bedeutung bekommen, dann hätte das Start-up auf das falsche Pferd gesetzt.
"To focus on sth." würde man im Deutschen eher ausdrücken als "sich auf etw. konzentrieren", "sich auf etw. fokussieren", "sein Hauptaugenmerk auf etw. richten". In der Praxis wird es häufig so sein, dass man sich auf das konzentriert, worauf man (sein Geld) gesetzt hat, aber es ist nicht das Gleiche.
Im Englischen würde man "auf etw. setzen" eher als "to bet on sth.", "to put one's money on sth." ausdrücken. Das kann ebenfalls im wörtlichen oder im übertragenen Sinn sein.

"Auf etwas setzen" wird man normalerweise Geld, z.B. eine Wette beim Pferderennen abschließen. Daher stammt auch die übertragene Bedeutung:
"Er setzt auf [Branche]" = Er glaubt, dass [Branche] an Bedeutung wachsen wird und investiert deshalb Geld.
Wenn ein Unternehmen "auf Nachhaltigkeit" setzt, ist beides gleichzeitig wahr die Geschäftsführung investiert Geld und wird höchstwahrscheinlich auch die Aktivität auf das Thema fokussieren. Die eigentliche Bedeutung ist aber der Einsatz von Geld (als Wette oder Investition) oder im übertragenen Sinne der Glaube an die Wichtigkeit.
